# Parsing BibTeX files in Java

Tags: java, parsing, tex

As part of a [larger project](https://bitbucket.org/Mangara/publy/src) to generate a website with a personal list of publications, I implemented a parser for [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/) files.

The entry point is the `parseFile` method in `PublicationListParser`. This method scans the file for entries (and [tags](https://bitbucket.org/Mangara/publy/wiki/Publication%20list%20format) - a custom extension specific to my project). Each entry is read into a `String` by `Tokenizer`, and then parsed by `BibItemParser`.

I'm looking for all kinds of feedback: style issues, missed corner cases, performance, logical organization, etc.

**PublicationListParser.java**

```
package publy.io.bibtexparser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import publy.Console;
import publy.data.Author;
import publy.data.bibitem.BibItem;

public class PublicationListParser {

    public static List<BibItem> parseFile(Path file) throws IOException, ParseException {
        Console.debug("Parsing publication list \"%s\"", file);
        PublicationListParser parser = new PublicationListParser();

        parser.parseFileInternal(file);
        AbbreviationHandler.handleAbbreviationsAndAuthors(parser.items, parser.abbreviations, parser.authors);

        return parser.items;
    }

    private final List<BibItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<String, String> abbreviations = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Author> authors = new HashMap<>();

    private PublicationListParser() {
    }

    private void parseFileInternal(Path file) throws IOException, ParseException {
        try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
            for (String l = in.readLine(); l != null; l = in.readLine()) {
                String line = l.trim();

                if (line.startsWith("@")) {
                    // A Bibitem
                    BibItem item = BibItemParser.parseBibItem(Tokenizer.collectBibItem(in, line).replaceAll("\\s+", " "));

                    if (item != null) {
                        switch (item.getType()) {
                            case COMMENT:
                            case PREAMBLE:
                                break; // Ignore
                            case STRING:
                                // Add to abbreviations
                                abbreviations.put(item.get("short"), item.get("full"));
                                break;
                            default:
                                items.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (line.startsWith("<")) {
                    // A custom tag
                    Tag tag = TagParser.parseTag(Tokenizer.collectTag(in, line).replaceAll("\\s+", " "));

                    if (tag.type == Tag.Type.ABBREVIATION) {
                        abbreviations.put(tag.values.get("short"), tag.values.get("full"));
                    } else if (tag.type == Tag.Type.AUTHOR) {
                        authors.put(tag.values.get("short"), tag.toAuthor());
                    } else {
                        throw new InternalError("Tag with unexpected type: " + tag);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tokenizer.java**

```
package publy.io.bibtexparser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import publy.data.Pair;

public class Tokenizer {

    public static String collectBibItem(BufferedReader input, String firstLine) throws IOException, ParseException {
        CombinedReader in = new CombinedReader(input, firstLine);
        StringBuilder bibitem = new StringBuilder();

        // Test for starting with '@'
        int c = in.read();

        if ((char) c != '@') {
            throw new ParseException("First character of bibitem should be '@'.");
        }

        // Scan for first open brace ('{')
        bibitem.appendCodePoint(c);
        c = in.read();

        while (c != -1 && (char) c != '{') {
            bibitem.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = in.read();
        }

        if (c == -1) {
            throw new ParseException("No opening brace found when trying to parse bibitem.");
        } else {
            bibitem.appendCodePoint(c);
        }

        // Collect the body
        collectMatchedToken(in, '{', '}', bibitem);

        return bibitem.toString();
    }

    public static String collectTag(BufferedReader input, String firstLine) throws IOException, ParseException {
        CombinedReader in = new CombinedReader(input, firstLine);
        StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder();

        // Test for starting with '<'
        int c = in.read();

        if ((char) c != '<') {
            throw new IOException("First character of tag should be '<'.");
        }

        tag.appendCodePoint(c);

        // Collect the body
        collectMatchedToken(in, '<', '>', tag);

        return tag.toString();
    }

    public static Pair<String, String> collectValue(String body) throws ParseException {
        // Collect until first "level-0" comma or close brace (end of bibitem)
        // When encountering an open brace, collect until we've matched it
        // When encountering a quote ("), collect until next quote

        int braceLevel = 0;
        boolean inQuotes = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < body.length(); i++) {
            int c = body.codePointAt(i);

            // Check braces
            if ((char) c == '{') {
                braceLevel++;
            } else if (braceLevel > 0 && (char) c == '}') {
                braceLevel--;
            } else if (braceLevel == 0) {
                // Check quotes
                if ((char) c == '"') {
                    inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                } else if (!inQuotes) {
                    if ((char) c == ',' || (char) c == '}') {
                        // zero-level end-of-value: we're done!
                        return new Pair<>(body.substring(0, i), body.substring(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        throw new ParseException(String.format("End of input reached while collecting value.%nText: %s", body));
    }

    /**
     * Collects characters from the input stream until the first time the number
     * of close characters seen is larger than the number of open characters.
     *
     * @param in
     * @param open
     * @param close
     * @return
     */
    private static void collectMatchedToken(CombinedReader in, char open, char close, StringBuilder result) throws ParseException, IOException {
        int openCount = 1;

        while (openCount > 0) {
            int c = in.read();

            if (c == -1) {
                if (open == '{') {
                    throw new ParseException("End of input reached while trying to match braces in bibitem body.");
                } else if (open == '<') {
                    throw new ParseException("End of input reached while trying to match angle brackets in tag body.");
                } else {
                    throw new ParseException("End of input reached while trying to match.");
                }
            }

            result.appendCodePoint(c);

            if ((char) c == open) {
                openCount++;
            } else if ((char) c == close) {
                openCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class CombinedReader {

        boolean endOfString = false;
        StringReader sr;
        BufferedReader br;

        public CombinedReader(BufferedReader br, String s) {
            this.sr = new StringReader(s);
            this.br = br;
        }

        public int read() throws IOException {
            if (endOfString) {
                return br.read();
            } else {
                int c = sr.read();

                if (c == -1) {
                    endOfString = true;
                    return br.read();
                } else {
                    return c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Tokenizer() {
    }
}
```

**BibItemParser.java**

```
package publy.io.bibtexparser;

import java.io.IOException;
import publy.Console;
import publy.data.Pair;
import publy.data.bibitem.BibItem;

public class BibItemParser {

    public static BibItem parseBibItem(String text) throws IOException, ParseException {
        int bodyStart = text.indexOf('{');
        String type = text.substring(1, bodyStart).trim().toLowerCase();
        String body = text.substring(bodyStart + 1).trim();

        switch (type) {
            case "comment":
            case "preamble":
                return new BibItem(type, null); // Ignore contents
            case "string":
                return parseString(body);
            default:
                return parsePublication(type, body);
        }
    }

    private static BibItem parseString(String body) {
        // Syntax: Short = "Full" or Short = {Full}
        int split = body.indexOf('=');
        String shortName = body.substring(0, split).trim();
        String fullText = body.substring(split + 1, body.length() - 1).trim(); // Remove outer '}'
        fullText = fullText.substring(1, fullText.length() - 1); // Remove outer pair of braces or quotation marks

        BibItem result = new BibItem("string", null);
        result.put("short", shortName);
        result.put("full", fullText);

        return result;
    }

    private static BibItem parsePublication(String type, String body) throws ParseException {
        // Syntax: id, (field-value-pair)*
        int idEnd = body.indexOf(',');

        if (idEnd == -1) {
            // No fields
            return new BibItem(type, body.substring(0, body.length() - 1));
        }

        String id = body.substring(0, idEnd).trim();
        body = body.substring(idEnd + 1).trim();

        BibItem result = new BibItem(type, id);

        while (!body.isEmpty() && !body.equals("}")) {
            // Parse the next field-value pair
            int valueStart = body.indexOf('=');

            if (valueStart == -1) {
                // No more field-value pairs, but text left: warn
                System.err.printf("After parsing all fields of publication \"%s\", the following text was left and not part of any field:\n%s\n", id, body);
                Console.warn(Console.WarningType.OTHER, "After parsing all fields of publication \"%s\", the following text was left and not part of any field:\n%s\n", id, body);
                break;
            }

            String field = body.substring(0, valueStart).trim().toLowerCase();
            body = body.substring(valueStart + 1).trim();

            Pair<String, String> value = Tokenizer.collectValue(body);
            result.put(field, parseValue(value.getFirst()));
            body = value.getSecond().trim();

            if (body.startsWith(",")) {
                body = body.substring(1).trim();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static String parseValue(String text) {
        // Drop outer pair of separators (braces or quotes)
        // Turn @string abbreviations into publy abbreviations ("<<short>>")
        // Process string concatenation

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int braceLevel = 0;
        boolean inQuotes = false;
        boolean inAbbreviation = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            int c = text.codePointAt(i);

            if (braceLevel > 0) {
                if ((char) c == '{') {
                    braceLevel++;
                } else if ((char) c == '}') {
                    braceLevel--;
                }

                if (braceLevel > 0 || inQuotes) {
                    // Add everything but the closing brace or quote
                    result.appendCodePoint(c);
                }
            } else if (inQuotes) {
                if ((char) c == '"') {
                    inQuotes = false;
                } else {
                    result.appendCodePoint(c);

                    if ((char) c == '{') {
                        braceLevel++;
                    } else if (braceLevel > 0 && (char) c == '}') {
                        braceLevel--;
                    }
                }
            } else if (inAbbreviation) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(c) || (char) c == '#' || (char) c == '{' || (char) c == '"') {
                    // End of abbreviation
                    result.append(">>");
                    inAbbreviation = false;

                    if ((char) c == '{') {
                        braceLevel = 1;
                    } else if ((char) c == '"') {
                        inQuotes = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    result.appendCodePoint(c);
                }
            } else {
                // Brace or quote start new tokens, pound is ignored, numbers just get parsed, text starts a new abbreviation token
                if ((char) c == '{') {
                    braceLevel = 1;
                } else if ((char) c == '"') {
                    inQuotes = true;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    result.appendCodePoint(c);
                } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                    result.append("<<");
                    result.appendCodePoint(c);
                    inAbbreviation = true;
                } // else ignore
            }
        }

        if (inAbbreviation) {
            result.append(">>");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    private BibItemParser() {
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the [full source code for the project on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/Mangara/publy/src).

Comment: Some questions: Is there anything you like or dislike about how the code is organized? The bitbucket README says that it "understands most Bib TeX files". What kind of Bibtex files can't it handle?

Comment: @user5402 Oh, right. That's out of date. I rewrote the parser from scratch. The old parser didn't handle string abbreviations, string concatenation, and crossref, but this one does.

Comment: @user5402 And I dislike how often the code goes over each part of the input. Using a real Tokenizer, as you suggested, would reduce that significantly, I suspect.

Comment: Not enough for a review but it disturbed me that your parser accepts a `Path` argument.  It would be much more flexible if it accepted an `InputStream`.  You can always add a convenience overload that opens and closes the file for the client and then delegates to the general method if you consider it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## .substring()

Note that .substring() values are not shared any more with the string
they were created from [(link)](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/).
That means calls like `body = body.substring(...).trim()`
will allocate two new strings: one for the `.substring(...)` and another
for the `.trim()`  which is another form of a sub-string.

So if you are concerned about efficiency, avoid marching through a string
by repeatedly taking substrings.

## use a library

I undersand this is Code Review, but since these seems to be a real
project, consider using a third party library like [jbibtex](https://github.com/jbibtex/jbibtex).
jbibtex is distributed under a liberal license and looks like
a very robust BiBTeX fle parser.

## use a tokenizer

You use several different methods for consuming input:

- reading a file line by line - `in.readline()`
- reading it one character at a time - `in.read()`
- indexing into a string, e.g. `body.codePointAt(i)`
- searching through a string. e.g. `body.indexOf(',')`
  followed by `body = body.substring(...)`.

I think you could make your life easier by tokenizing the
input and parse the file at the token level.
This would, for instance, get rid of the multiple `.trim()` calls
all over the place since ignoring white space would be
the job of the tokenizer and thus handled in one place.

An example of a tokenizer is the class `java.io.StreamTokenizer`.
It has two main methods:

- `.nextToken()`
- `.pushBack()`

`.pushBack()` pushes the last token returned by `.nextToken()` back
onto the stream so that it will be returned again by the
next `.nextToken()`.

A tokenizer makes it easy to wmanually write a
recursive descent parser for simple grammars
like a BibTeX file.

Here is a blog post on writing a recursive descent parser
with StreamTokenizer to parse boolean expressions:

https://unnikked.ga/how-to-evaluate-a-boolean-expression/

**Update**

Here is an example of how to roll your own parser - written in Python:

https://gist.github.com/erantapaa/5a2614adde0526d25c03

Comment: Thanks! These are all excellent suggestions. I had looked for existing parsers before writing this, but clearly not enough. I'll take a look at jbibtex and see if I can plug it in.

Comment: In case you still need to write your own parser, this page seems like it would be very helpful in understanding what the `bibtex` program accepts as valid input: [__A summary of BibTeX__](http://maverick.inria.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/xdkbibtex/bibtex_summary.html)

Comment: You're right, that's a great resource. I already found one bug in my current implementation: it doesn't accept entries contained in pairs of parentheses.

Comment: Answer updated. I wrote some Python code which demonstrates one way to roll your own parser from scratch. Should be easily transferrable to Java.

Answer (score 2):

You have very large `if` code blocks that I can't help but wonder if it will be better to extract them as methods.

For `CombinedReader`, maybe you can consider setting the `StringReader` to `null` when there is no more to be read from it:

```
private static class CombinedReader {
    private StringReader stringReader;
    // this you can make final
    private final BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    // note: reordered arguments so that it reads like 
    // the String is 'used' first, followed by the BufferedReader
    public CombinedReader(String s, BufferedReader br) {
        this.stringReader = new StringReader(s);
        this.bufferedReader = br;
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (stringReader != null) {
            int c = stringReader.read();
            if (c != -1) {
                return c;
            }
            stringReader = null;
        }
        return bufferedReader.read();
    }
}
```

**edit:** An example of extracting `if` code blocks as methods for `PublicationListParser`:

```
private void parseFileInternal(Path file) throws IOException, ParseException {
    try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
        for (String l = in.readLine(); l != null; l = in.readLine()) {
            String line = l.trim();
            if (line.startsWith("@")) {
                handleBibItem(BibItemParser.parseBibItem(
                                normalize(Tokenizer.collectBibItem(in, line))));
            } else if (line.startsWith("<")) {
                handleTag(TagParser.parseTag(
                            normalize(Tokenizer.collectTag(in, line))));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static String normalize(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
}

private void handleBibItem(BibItem item) {
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }
    switch (item.getType()) {
        case COMMENT:
        case PREAMBLE:
            break; // Ignore
        case STRING:
            // Add to abbreviations
            abbreviations.put(item.get("short"), item.get("full"));
            break;
        default:
            items.add(item);
    }
}

private void handleTag(Tag tag) {
    switch (tag.type) {
        case Tag.Type.ABBREVIATION:
            abbreviations.put(tag.values.get("short"), tag.values.get("full"));
            break;
        case Tag.Type.AUTHOR:
            authors.put(tag.values.get("short"), tag.toAuthor());
            break;
        default:
            throw new InternalError("Tag with unexpected type: " + tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of one of my `if` blocks that would be better as a separate method?

Comment: @Mangara updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! And you're right, that's much clearer. I'll see if I can do the same thing elsewhere.